# I am getting an error "Notice: Undefined index: distribution_name in drupal_install_profile_distribution_name() ". How do I fix this?

Tags: 7

I am using Drupal 7.69. I log in and go to my modules page and get the following error:

> Notice: Undefined index: distribution_name in drupal_install_profile_distribution_name() (line 207 of /var/www/html/includes/install.inc).

According to this page: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/1170362, you're supposed to run the following update SQL statement to set the correct status: `UPDATE system SET status=1 WHERE name='standard';`

My problem is in my system table I don't have any record with name equal to "standard". How do I add it?

Comment: What distribution are you using? They tend to include installation profiles, you just need to find the machine name of the one you used to install the site and replace `standard` with that name in the update query

Comment: Also, that is a notice, not an error. If the page is correctly showing the installed modules, you can ignore that notice, or set Drupal so that notices aren't visible in any page.

Answer (score 0):

After seeing the results of drupal_get_profile() and querying for that value in the system table, the result of the query showed that the profile's files were (supposed to be) in:

```
/var/www/html/profiles/[profile name]/
```

However, that folder path did not exist. Since Drupal could not find the profile's files in that folder path, it could not set a distribution_name.

I found the correct profile files in my original download from way back in the day, re-uploaded them to the correct directory on my server and cleared the cache. The message disappeared.